# CSS moving element from one div to another

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am wondering please what is the best way to move an element from one div to another in responsive design?

I have the current setup in my page:

```
        <div class="container">
         <div class="desktop"><h2>Hello I show on desktop</h2></div>
         <div class="mobile"><h2>Hello I show on mobile</h2></div>
        </div>
```

And then the relevant CSS media queries to either display the mobile or desk top version and it works...but is it the right way?

Comment: Yes, that would be the correct way of doing it. Hide `.desktop` on mobile, and hide `.mobile` on desktop.

Comment: Instead of duplicating HTML content - you could have only one HELLO and a class for it like `.hello` and use media queries to change the styles depending on the media  size, type and other variants like portrait etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to design the page for mobile. Then add the stuff that's required for desktop. Share as much as possible and try not to duplicate content on the same page.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Hello world!</h2>
    <div class="desktop">
        this is an extended block only visible on desktop
    </div>
    <p>
        this text is visible from both
    </p>
</div>
```

You can also try bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com - it does a lot - including dynamic resizing of images and columns. It's really worth trying - might save you a whole bunch of work.

Comment: Exactly. (Just... Bootstrap...? It's not that hard to grasp the basics of media queries and the needed meta)

Comment: A simple media query might be enough for the start - just like in the other answers here.

But things grow. Sooner or later you'll add columns, images etc. Suddenly things get complicated. This is why I propose using Bootstrap. It gives you a solid framework for all this.

... except if just plan on creating a hello world page. Then it's of course overkill.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right or wrong way but the way you are doing it is perfectly suitable.

```
.desktop{
  display:block;
}
.mobile{
  display:none;
}

@media all and (max-width:400px){
  .desktop{
    display:none;
  }
  .mobile{
    display:block;
  }
}
```

---

Personally I only use one div and make it responsive.

```
.desktop{
  width:100%;
  font-size:1em;
}
@media all and (max-width:400px){
  .desktop{
    font-size: 0.7em;
  }
}
```

Comment: I know he simply asked if it was the right way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes**, you are doing it right. Use media queries for the two different classes like below.

```css
.mobile,
.desktop {
  display: block;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="desktop">
    <h2>Hello I show on desktop</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile">
    <h2>Hello I show on mobile</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup. So how do we answer such questions? :) Just asking as you are more experienced here.